# Creating subquery in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.6

How can I convert the following SQL query into Laravel query builder? Can anyone help?

```
SELECT email,user from (select email,user_id as user from businesses ) as ui WHERE user > 1
```

Comment: Is this a multi-tenant project? Why not use package that solves this already? https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant/tree/5.x

Comment: Is this the whole query? Why are you using a subquery?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir This is my query and i need to use it as a subquery for a particular process.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```php
DB::query()->select('email', 'user')
    ->fromSub(function($query) {
        $query->select('email', 'user_id as user')
            ->from('businesses');
    }, 'ui')
    ->where('user', '>', 1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?